# How is probability related to function mappings?

Tags: probability, functions

**Let P = {a,b,c} and Q={1,2,3,4}.
If a function f: P→Q is chosen uniformly at random (from the set of all such functions), what is the probability that f is injective?**

I know that an injective function is one in which every element in the co-domain is an image of at most one element in the domain.

But how do I find the probability?

Comment: How many functions from $P$ to $Q$ are there without restriction?  How many of these are injective?

Comment: 64 functions in total, out of which 24 are injective. Now how do I calculate the probability?

Comment: I get it, 24/64. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.   Well, better to reduce it to $\frac 38$.